# Unable to pass array argument to thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a while and if loop that calls a thread and passes in the array `command`. It looks like this:

```
from Threading import Thread

def myfunction(command):
   print(command)

while True
   command = input()
   if command="1":
      t = Thread(target=myfunction, args=(command, ))
      t.start()
      t.daemon()
```

However, it tells me that I have passed a bool and throws an error

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

I've also tried passing in `command` as a string, but I get the same error.

Comment: error shouls show you what function it treats as bool value. Maybe you assign `True/False` to some variable and when you use this variable as function you have `True() / False()``

Answer (score 1):

Several problems in this code:

- `Threading` should be `threading`
- `while True` should be `while True:`
- `if command = "1"` (assignment) should be `if command == "1"` (comparison)

And, the reason for the error in the question:

`Thread.daemon` is not a function. It's a property that returns a boolean hence `t.daemon()` is causing the `bool is not callable` error.

I think you meant to set it to `True` and it must be done before `.start` is called:

```
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

It would be better to set during initialization:

```
t = Thread(target=myfunction, args=(command, ), daemon=True)
```

Comment: `t.daemon(True)` is also wrong - the correct way is to simply do `t.daemon = True` (or pass it to the constructor, of course).

Comment: @zvone Indeed, fixed

Answer (score -1):

Your condition is not actually a condition, but an assignment as it uses `=` operator. It needs to be an equality check `==`.

```
if command == "1":
```